# ParseObject#pin lock the thread

Tags: android, parse-platform

I use `ParseObject.pin` method in `AsyncTaskLoader.loadInBackground` and it just lock the thread. Why? how to avoid it?

**UPD** code example

```
public class MyLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Object>{
    @Override
    public Object loadInBackground() {
        HashMap params = new HashMap();
        try {
            HashMap result = ParseCloud.callFunction("myFunction",params);
            ParseObject object = (ParseObject) result.get("some_field");
            object.fetchIfNeeded();
            object.pin();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this issue https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/61 there is a linear time dependency. so pinning can take a lot of time. It seams like thread locking.